# Drag from JQGrid to jsTree v.0.9.9a

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, drag-and-drop, jstree

I am looking to drag a row from the jqGrid I have created and fire a drop event on a node in the jsTree (v.0.9.9a).

Is there anyway to do this - **using v.0.9.9a** of the jsTree only.

Regards.

Comment: I know i can loop through each <li> tag in the jstree and apply .droppable() and loop through each <tr> tag in the grid and apply .draggable(), but i wonder if there is not a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much debate, i've decided to switch to jsTree version 1.

In jqGrid I added the event

```
afterInsertRow: function (rowid, rowdata, rowelem) {
            $("#" + rowid).addClass('jstree-draggable');
        },
```

I then added the dnd plugin for the jstree, which allows all external elements with the class "jstree-draggable" to be dragged into the tree with the event `"drag_finish": function (data) {}` in the jsTree.

While jsTree version 1 is a pain to switch to after using pre-Version 1 it really is a lot faster, neater and easier to use once you get the hang of it. I'm told that full documentation will be released with the version 1 final.

Answer (score 0):

This is a really narrow question. It sounds like both controls use the jQuery UI draggable and droppable widgets, and that you have a preliminary approach. Why not try implementing your idea and see how well it works?

I would encourage you to post your code when you are done, or if you get stuck along the way...

Answer (score 0):

just:

```
$("#treeOptions").jstree({
   plugins: ["themes", "json_data", "dnd", "ui", "types"],
   ...
   dnd: { drag_target: ".jqgrow" }
   ...
});
```