# Is it possible to drag and drop from jstree to jqgrid?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jqgrid, drag-and-drop, jstree

looks like it is possible to drag and drop from jqgrid to jstree.  [Drag from JQGrid to jsTree v.0.9.9a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3300258/drag-from-jqgrid-to-jstree-v-0-9-9a)   .  is it possible to drag and drop from jstree to jqgrid?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately no one has made a plugin for it yet. It's possible, it would just involve you figuring out how to do it. Might be worth a try. I'm sure a lot of people would use it/find it helpful since there is no plugin that does the job at the moment.